# pod got killed as soon as created by job

Tags: tensorflow, kubernetes

Pod created by job gets killed with Message:

```
Normal DeadlineExceeded Job was active longer than specified deadline
```

This is a pod running training process with Tensorflow. The weird thing is this pod is just created with no thing error in `kubectl log` output.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#job-termination-and-cleanup you can see that `DeadlineExceeded` means your process run longer then the longest time it is allowed to in your spec.

Comment: yeah, I have read that manual. I thought it means job controller recreates a new pod and starts timing after first pod fails. When timeout to Deadline specified, job controller will kill and delete the existing pods. In that case, when run `kubectl describe job`, we can see `0 Succeed/ 0 Running/ 1 Failed`. 
However, the events output shows that the job controller killed and deleted the pod as soon as it failed. That is confusing